# Cannot import library in notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm running a jupyter notebook in a virtual environment. I cannot import some of the libraries that are installed in the env, and I can't figure out what is wrong.

What I do is cd into the project folder, and start the virtual environment, then start jupyter lab:

```
cd code
source env/bin/activate
jupyter lab
```

But then I cannot import the libraries installed specifically in the env, example

[image]

But in a python interpreter in the same folder, same env I can import the same library without problem

[image]

How can I find the reason for the problem?

Comment: Did you install Jupyter in the virtual env? Check with `pip list`.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run `jupyter lab`
Add the virtual environment as a jupyter kernel

```
(your-venv)$ ipython kernel install --name "env" --user
```

See [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-jupyter-notebook-in-virtual-environment/) as reference.